# How to calculate the shortest steps for this chess

Tags: java

Chinese chess has 8*8=64 cells. And the point is (1, 1), (1, 2)... (8, 8).

And the horse walks by diagonal line of two cells from the point it is on.

Calculate the shortest step(s) between two points for the horse to walk. For example

> (1, 1) to (4, 4). Horse goes like this (1, 1) > (2, 3) > (4, 4) 2 steps

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. However, I'd suggest looking at the [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm for searching the board for the shortest path to the destination square.

Comment: Hint : convert your 8x8 into a graph then apply djikstra's algorithm. But please do not ask us to do your homework.

Comment: Chinese chess's board is 9x10 lines. It doesn't work on the cells

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the chess board to a graph then you can use a pathfinding algorithm like dijkstra :

[image]

Comment: you are misunderstanding.Im talking about chinese chess

Comment: @BruceCing I do not know chinese chess but the algorithm is still valid. Is it this game? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi#mediaviewer/File:MovementOfHorsePiece.png

Answer (score 0):

1. create `Integer board[8][8]`
2. set start point as 0.
3. found all points where horse can move from start point and set it to 1.
4. for all points that set to 1 find all unseted points where horse can move from them and set it to 2.
5. repeat this algo until end point will be seted. Number at the end point is count of steps.

If you want to get path you must go from end point to start point in this board:

1. at the end point contains N.
2. find any point where horse can move from end point and that contains N-1.
3. repeat until you reach start point.
4. revert this path.

Comment: You've just described [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). However, you need a way to track the actual path. (Note that he wants the _path_ as the result, not the move count.)

Answer (score -1):

check Bresenham's algorithm. it is good algorithm for this problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: This is definitely not the right answer. Think of this scenario: The horse is at (3,3), and you want to move it to (4,3). How does this algorithm help figure out a legal path?